# Does puphpet install vm on digitalocean?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, digital-ocean

I think I understand puppet and vagrant pretty well however I might have confused myself.

So I created a Puppet setup using [puphpet.com](http://puphpet.com) and I chose **Digital Ocean** as my deploy target, I then enter my API key and all is well.

The final step they say is to run `vagrant up`.

I am guessing this installs a virtual machine on my local machine and creates a Digital Ocean droplet then runs the puppet manifest on that new droplet and virtual machine locally.

My main issue is: I am unsure on whether it installs a virtual machine within my droplet or not?

Could someone help explain the process of what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Vagrant itself is just a wrapper around a hypervisor such as Virtualbox or a cloud provider like DigitalOcean.

The Vagrant DigitalOcean plugin will use the API to create a server to interact with, and then it will copy your files up and run them on the created server.

If you pick Digital Ocean as your deploy target, when you run `vagrant up` it will create a server, then install Puppet on it, copy up the required manifests and install the stack you have requested.

From a quick test I just run, if you pick DigitalOcean as the provider, it will not created a VM on your local machine, it will only create the DigitalOcean server.

Comment: So for a live environment is this ok ? it seems pretty simple. Thank you for the edit btw

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. If you want a simple way of repeatably creating a server that you can test on it works great. However, unless you save the .vagrant/ directory, it will create a new server every-time you run `vagrant up`.

Comment: ahhh yeah I see what you mean, so what would be an alternative solution for live be ?

Comment: Well, that's a larger question, probably for http://serverfault.com/ :) But the short answer is after the server has been created, you can store the IP and SSH details and log in with something else. Or you could use a tool such as https://github.com/pearkes/tugboat to orchestrate your Digital Ocean droplets.

Comment: ahhhh, so I can use vagrant and puppet to create the instances then all I need to do is manage them. I thought I knew what I was talking about at one point of my life

Comment: Indeed :) No problem, there's a lot of moving parts, it can get a bit complicated sometimes! :D